# Calculating the forward vector of an object that has been rotated.

Tags: vectors

I am trying to implement a character movement system from scratch and wanted to know how would I calculate the forward vector of an object that has been rotated around a certain axis. Similar to how unity calculates the transform.forward vector by taking into account how the object has been rotated.

In this picture you can see that the object is at the origin and is currently unrotated. The x,y,z axis are represented by the red, green and blue colors respectively. I can simply move the object in the forward direction by adding the vector (1,0,0) to the object's current position

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjHz1.png)

In this image I have rotated the object around the y axis by 45 degrees. Now I want to calculate the forward vector of this object so that I can move the object forward on the x axis by adding to the current position in the angle that it is rotated in.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVaus.png)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Are you sure? Asking how to apply a spatial rotation to a vector sounds quite on-topic to me. The fact that the problem seems to come from game coding or 3d modeling or something similar isn't really relevant.

Comment: broadly speaking, you need to understand what a 'rotation matrix' is to have easy answers to this problem

Comment: Sorry should I post this question on stack overflow instead?

Comment: I do understand that the rotation matrix is used to get the coordinates of the point when it is rotated by an angle theta.  But I still don't understand how would I go about solving this problem.

Comment: An example would help clarify your question. How are you representing position, orientation, rotation, directions, etc.? Currently you don't even say whether you're working in 2D or 3D, although we can infer it's 3D.